# Node Executable in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, sentry

I am attempting to build an AWS Lambda (Node) function that utilizes the [Sentry CLI](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli). So far I have something like:

```
const CLI = require("@sentry/cli");

const cli = new CLI(null, {
  org: '...',
  authToken: '...',
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const response = await cli.execute(["releases", "list"]);

  // ...create a release/deploy/etc...
};
```

This however fails with:

> /var/task/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli: cannot execute binary file

There seems to have been a similar [issue reported](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/issues/747) and the suggestion is to change the permission of the executable.

How can I ensure that the permissions on the executable are not stripped when zipping/uploading the function to AWS?

Comment: Isn't there a [sentry NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/node) you could use instead of shelling out to the cli?

Comment: Isn't the Sentry CLI [already](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/cli) an NPM package?

Comment: @jarmod Yes however I don't believe that you can create releases/deploys w/ it–AFAIK that can only be done w/ the CLI but I could be wrong.

Comment: @KyleDecot could you please share the issue link on Github? The current link points to the repo homepage, not the issue. Thanks

Comment: Also, this AWS [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-deployment.html) says to use a `chmod` to fix the issue

Comment: so think if it's done locally and then uploaded, it should still work.

Comment: @PranavKasetti sorry about that–the link has been updated.

Comment: I see, thanks! :) I checked out the link now. Seems to say that if the file/dir permissions are OK locally then the uploaded files should also have the right permissions. So just wanted to check if your local executable permission is `+x`?

Comment: Otherwise, I think updating the function code again could work (as I wrote in my answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

```
chmod 644 $(find . -type f)
chmod 755 $(find . -type d)
chmod +x ./node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli // Same command for other binaries as well
// Reupload function code using update-function code using steps below.
```

## Deep dive

This answer is a **summary** of the **steps outlined in the docs**, **with additional explanations** for why they are needed and **prerequisites/debugging workflows** if anything goes wrong. The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html) suggest the following steps for uploading NodeJS projects with additional dependencies as follows. I have **designed the steps with an existing AWS Lambda instance already running** to help limit the scope of the error when debugging (to AWS or Sentry).

### (Recommended) Steps with existing project

1.1 Install Node w/NPM locally (I assume you've done this). Make a note of your local node version and check this matches AWS Lambda instance.

```
$ node -v
```

1.2 Install the AWS CLI (**must be [version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html)!**).

1.3 Configure the AWS CLI with:

```
$ aws configure
```

**Note:** You can configure this manually as well if you need to with [different guides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html) for each platform. I will leave these details out since they are straightforward.

1.4 Try **deploying a `hello-world` Lambda first** and see if that works **without** the sentry-cli package. If it does work, you know sentry is probably the issue and NOT AWS.

1.5 Install Sentry CLI:

```
$ npm install @sentry/cli
```

1.6 Automatic `sentry-cli` configuration:

```
$ sentry-cli login
```

1.7 Verify your `sentry-cli` config is valid with `$ sentry-cli info`. If not, you need to follow the steps recommended in the console output.

```
$ sentry-cli info
```

1.8 Install dependencies using `aws-xray-sdk`:

```
$ npm install aws-xray-sdk
```

1.8.1 (**Optional**) Navigate to your project root folder. This is just for illustration; the current version of the AWS SDK is pre-installed in Lambda, but you could use this technique **to load other pre-built JavaScript packages** or if you actually needed an earlier version of the AWS SDK for compatibility reasons (not applicable).

```
$ npm install --prefix=. aws-sdk
```

1.8.2 (**Sanity Check**) Check the permissions of all files in the subfolders of root directory have the executable permissions. Try running the project locally, to see if the executable permission exists:

```
$ ls -l && node function.js
```

1.9 Zip the project:

```
$ zip -r function.zip . // The .zip file must be **less than 50 MB**!
```

1.10 Upload the function code using the **aws command-line tool** `update-function-code` (this is important **because this will fix the permissions issue**.

```
$ aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-function --zip-file fileb://function.zip
```

1.11 If the operation was successful, you will get an output like the following:

```
{
    "FunctionName": "my-function",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:my-function",
    "Runtime": "nodejs12.x",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/lambda-role",
    "Handler": "index.handler",
    "CodeSha256": "Qf0hMc1I2di6YFMi9aXm3JtGTmcDbjniEuiYonYptAk=",
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "Active"
    },
    "RevisionId": "983ed1e3-ca8e-434b-8dc1-7d72ebadd83d",
    ...
}
```

1.12 If you get an error with the upload, for example, you can follow the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-exceptions.html). Check the AWS logs if you need to on [AWS CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-logging.html#nodejs-logging-cwconsole).

1.13 Test the running lambda, after you are sure that the `update-function-code` was successful.

```
$ aws lambda invoke --function-name my-function --payload '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}' output.txt
```

### Another potential solution (not ideal)

Make the sentry cli executable before you run the `CLI` config command using [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;    
child = exec('chmod +x /var/task/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
             console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    });
child();
```

**Alternative**: You can also try using this [package](https://github.com/lambrospetrou/aws-lambda-binary).

### Refactoring with Sentry Node NPM package

If in the steps above, you notice that the Sentry CLI is the issue, you can try to refactor your code without this package. Use the [Sentry Node NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/node) instead since this NPM package was built for NodeJS, and maybe refactor your code. The Sentry Node may be easier to get running but doesn't have functions for deployment/release. From their `Usage` [page](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/usage/):

> Sentry's SDK hooks into your runtime environment and automatically reports errors, exceptions, and rejections.

### (Note) Sentry with AWS Lambda Docs

The Sentry [docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/guides/aws-lambda/) recommend using the `@sentry/serverless` as a package for integration with AWS Lambda. If you don't want to refactor your code use [this guide](https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/aws-lambda/).

> With the AWS Lambda integration enabled, the Node SDK will:
>
> - Automatically report all events from your Lambda Functions.
> - Allows you to modify the transaction sample rate using tracesSampleRate.
> - Issue reports automatically include:
> - A link to the cloudwatch logs
> - Function details
>
>   - sys.argv for the function
>   - AWS Request ID
>   - Function execution time
>   - Function version

## Caveats:

1. The .zip file **must be less than 50 MB**. If it's larger than 50 MB, Amazon recommends uploading it to an Amazon Simple Storage Service (**Amazon S3**) bucket.
2. The .zip file can't contain libraries written in C or C++. If your .zip file contains C-extension libraries, such as the Pillow (PIL) or numpy libraries, we recommend using the AWS Serverless Application Model (AWS SAM) command line interface (CLI) to build a deployment package.
3. The .zip file must contain your function's code and any dependencies used to run your function's code (if applicable) on Lambda. If your function depends only on standard libraries, or AWS SDK libraries, you don't need to include these libraries in your .zip file. These libraries are included with the supported Lambda runtime environments.
4. If any of the libraries **use native code, use an Amazon Linux** environment to create the deployment package. Also, ensure you package the native code (if you have some) locally on the **same platform as the Lambda**!
5. If your deployment package contains native libraries, you can build the deployment package with AWS Serverless Application Model (`AWS SAM`). You can use the AWS SAM CLI sam `build` command with the `--use-container` to create your deployment package. This option builds a deployment package inside a Docker image that is compatible with the Lambda execution environment.